# Transforming SOAP WS output to an .xsd complaint XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, xsd

I have a `SOAP` based Web Service which returns back an `XML` response. I need to convert this `XML` into another `XML` which should be compatible with a provided `XSD` file.

Is there any opensource Java framework which can help me in achieving this `XML` transformation per the `XSD` file? Will appreciate any  help or pointers on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you imagining a system that, given an XSD file, can transform arbitrary XML into XSD-compliant XML? Because I think that "do what I mean" systems have not yet been invented. ;-) -- Or rather a system that transforms given XML given a predefined set of rules?

Comment: Thanks Tomalak! I was expecting (or imagining :) ) a framework which could help me convert XMl into another xsd compliant XML. I understand that we would need to do some sort of mapping of old and new nodes but is there any java framework that you know which can help me in this?

Comment: No, I don't know such a framework, sorry. But if you need a rather static mapping from A to B, writing an XLST stylesheet might be the least trouble. If you provide the input format and the set of rules, I can help you get started. Appyling XLST to XML is a handful lines of Java code, and the XSLT itself might not be complicated, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a recommendation, if you are more comfortable with java than xsd/xml:

Assume that your first soap response xml is compliant with first.xsd and the second one is second.xsd. Generate the java types for each using [xjc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/jaxb/xjc.html), which comes with jdk1.6.

Now the exercise will be to simply convert instance of one type to other and serizalize.

Basically,
First.xml -> First java Type -> Second Java Type -> Second.xml

If absolutely needed, you can even use the [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) framework to convert across java bean types

Comment: I just realized that this is an awesome answer - gets around the complexity of xsd/xml/xslt development by leveraging Java !

Answer (score 1):

XSL transformation is the standard way to tranform XML to XML. You can use [xalan engine](http://xalan.apache.org/) to do the transformation